# Aptana - remove side by side editor windows/tabs

Tags: ide, aptana

Recently I was using Aptana to view multiple files side by side. The unfortunate thing is that now I can not remove the editor (side by side) windows that are marked by red arrows. Also, you can obviously see that I have been trying to drag them away which is making the problem worse. I have tried to Google around but have found no solution. I can uninstall and reinstall Aptana, but if there is a fix I would rather know it and not have to go through a reinstallation process each time an issue like this arises.
Also I would like to add that I may be having trouble Googling the solution since I am not 100% sure on the name of the "editor tabs". Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My reputation is too low so here is a image link of my issue:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddxxv.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is extremely simple. If you ever run into the issue as shown in the picture above, simply open new files and drag them into the empty spaces that the extra "editor windows" are located. From there just close (x) out the window and it will remove the extra windows.